# Jquery ajax get method not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using the following code but it seems to be not working. Sorry for asking this simple question but I want to know why this code is not working

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.get("smiley1.html",function(data,status){
      alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<button>Send an HTTP GET request to a page and get the result back</button>
```

Please help me to solve it. Thanks

Comment: what's not working? error ??

Comment: when i run this code it does not return the result from that page nor it shows that ajax request in the firebug.

Comment: Did you include the jQuery library?

Comment: obviously i included jquery library

Comment: Just making sure. Some people forget to include it

Comment: You can create a file named smiley1.html & place some html code into it & run this code it will not show alert box. It means its not executing. How can i execute it?

Comment: any console log errors ?

Comment: No console log errors

Comment: I tried jquery 1.9 and even jquery 1.11 but still its not working. I have seen an eg on w3schools that eg is working on w3schools but when i ran that same eg changing the file name in $.get() it didnt run.

Comment: jQuery `.get` function only calls the *success* function if the request succeeds. I tested your code and it works for me. Make sure your page is loaded with an `http://` URL and not a `file://` URL. Try adding a link `<a href="smiley1.html">smiley</a>` on your existing page, and test if the link works.

Comment: Thank You Tom for your suggestions. When I used http:// instead of file:// the code worked for me. Thanks a lot but one thing I want to ask why it require http:// why cant it works with file://

Comment: AJAX doesn't work with local files, only with servers.

Answer (score 0):

Code is fine but, it matter from where you are running it. 
If you are trying to run from snippet runner of this page, if will fail because of 2 reasons

1. it doesn't find $ (i.e. jQuery)
2. it is trying to do cross domain call, which I believe is not allowed from target page. **smiley1.html** is not present on stackoverflow.com domain, 
   you can see error in developers console

If try it in jsfiddle

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.get("x2rmptu3/show/",function(data,status){
      alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
  });
});
```

here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/x2rmptu3/2/

Comment: I dont know why this code is not running. I placed both of the files in the same folder: smiley1.html & index.html. I even included jquery file. Can you tell me is there any problem with my firefox?

Comment: @RohanSharma Can you share sample code via dropbox or jsfiddle ?

Comment: Sorry Sangram, for delay replying. When i used http:// instead of file:// it worked for me. Thank you for your interest.